# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'url_request' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

Think I'm going nuts here.

```
url_request = 0

def somefunction():
    url_request+=1

if __name__ =='__main__':
    somefunction()
```

Gives me the UnboundLocalError. What important concept am I missing here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are assigning to a global variable, which means you need to *mark* it as a global:

```
def somefunction():
    global url_request
    url_request+=1
```

When you assign to a variable in a local scope, it is assumed to be a local variable unless you use a `global` statement to tell python otherwise first.

Comment: Didn't even think for a second that `+=` was doing an assignment.

Answer (score 6):

For Python 2.7 we have to types of variables: global, local. Each function create it's own local scope for variables.

From local scope you can **read** without any restrictions. You can also **call** global object methods, so you can **modify** variable from global. But you can't **reassign** value.

Look at this code:

```
requests = [1,2,3]

def modify():
    requests.append(4)

def redeclare():
    requests = [10,20,30]

modify()
print requests
# will give you [1,2,3,4]

redeclare()
print requests
# will give you [1,2,3,4]
```

What's going on? You can't reassign `requests` variable from local scope, so interpreter create for you **other** variable - in local scope for `redeclare` call context.

Regarding to your code... Firstly, you try to reassign variable from global scope. Why? `url_request` is `int`, `int` is immutable, so operation `url_request+=1` doesn't **change** value, it should reassign new value to variable name. Secondly, you don't specify `global` identify for this variable. So only one option for interpreter - to assume `url_request` as local variable. But... You didn't declare it's value anywhere....

`UnboundLocalError` means that you try to perform operations with variable value without declaring it before. Hope this will help you to understand more about Python variables/names/scopes.