# Preparing url in a Python(2.7) parser code

Tags: python, csv, html-parsing

When we search a book on https://www.worldcat.org/ it will give all the related editions(View all editions), now I want to collect the related editions of each book and all their information. The input of the following code is a csv file with the ISBNs of some books, the output is a csv file with the collected information.

```
import csv
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import time
import requests
import os
from subprocess import check_output

class Request(object):
    """docstring for Request"""
    def __init__(self, url):
        super(Request, self).__init__()
        self.url = url
        self.headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

    def make(self, query=None, resource=None):
        if query:
            params = {'qt': 'worldcat_org_all'}
            params['q'] = query
            url = self.url + '/search'
        elif resource:
            url = self.url + resource
            params = None
        r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=self.headers)#line25
        if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok: #a property called ok in the Response object that returns True if the status code is not a  4xx or a 5xx.
            return r.text
        else:
            try:#If we made a bad request (a 4XX client error or 5XX server error response), we can raise it
                r.raise_for_status()
            except Exception, e:
                if r.status_code == 403:
                    print ("\n\n===================   Execution stopped!   ===================")
                    sys.exit(e)
            return None

class ResponseManager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ResponseManager, self).__init__()

    def get_resource(self, html_doc, text_to_find):
        """This obtains:
        1. view all editions
        2. next pages
        """
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
        links = soup.find_all('a') #a is the tag for every web link
        resource = None
        for link in links:
            if text_to_find in link.text.lower() and not resource:
                resource = link.get('href')
        return resource

    def get_resource_titles(self, html_doc):
        """
        This method returns all resources related to titles.
        """
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
        links = soup.find_all('a')
        resources = []
        for link in links:
            href = link.get('href')#get is a dictionary method returns a value for the given key
            if href and '/title' in href and not href in resources:
                resources.append(href)
        return resources

    def get_ISBN_code(self, html_doc):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
        tr_element = soup.find(id="details-standardno")#standardno?
        if tr_element:
            return tr_element.td.string
        else:
            return None

def get_resource_titles_all_pages(html_doc, resources, r_manager):
    #the difference with the get_resource_titles function is that this function searches in all pages.
    resource = r_manager.get_resource(html_doc, 'next')
    if resource:#if the last one
        # os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')#Execute the command (a string) in a subshell
        # print ("getting...", resource)
        html_doc = request.make(resource=resource)
        resources_tmp = r_manager.get_resource_titles(html_doc)#returns all resources related to titles
        resources += resources_tmp
        return get_resource_titles_all_pages(html_doc, resources, r_manager)
        #the recursive function here call it self, why? 
        #it is finding the related books of the already found related books, until a related book in the chain has no related ones.
    else:
        return resources

wc = int(check_output(["wc", "-l", sys.argv[1]]).split()[0]) - 1 #total entries/books
inputFile = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
outputFile = open(sys.argv[2], 'wb')

inputFileReader = csv.reader(inputFile)
outputFileWriter = csv.writer(outputFile, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

lineCounter = 0
request = Request('https://www.worldcat.org')
r_manager = ResponseManager() #just simplifies class name
codes_not_found = []

for row in inputFileReader:
    if(lineCounter == 0):
        print("%s Start Job !" % datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    else:
        ISBN_code_digit10 = row[0]
        ISBN_code_digit13 = row[1]

        if(ISBN_code_digit10 == 10):
            ISBN_code = ISBN_code_digit10
        else: 
            ISBN_code = ISBN_code_digit13

        html_doc = request.make(query=ISBN_code)#search this ISBN
        resource = r_manager.get_resource(html_doc, 'view all editions')

        if(resource): #within the available related books
            tempRowStorage = []
            tempRowStorage.append(row[0])#first two cells are the 10 and 13-ISBN inputs
            tempRowStorage.append(row[1])

            digits13Storage = set()#unordered collection with no duplicate elements.
            digits10Storage = set()

            html_doc = request.make(resource=resource)
            resources = r_manager.get_resource_titles(html_doc)#get all links
            resources = get_resource_titles_all_pages(html_doc, resources, r_manager)
            for resource in resources:
                html_doc = request.make(resource=resource)#resource has changed from that of line 125
                if html_doc:
                    ISBN_code_related = r_manager.get_ISBN_code(html_doc)#actually we are not getting ISBNs only, 
                    if ISBN_code_related:
                        resourceQueryResult = ISBN_code_related.split(" ") #breakdown a large string, by space

                        for isbn in resourceQueryResult:
                            if(len(isbn) == 13 and isbn != ISBN_code_digit13):
                                digits13Storage.add(isbn) #collecting all related 13-ISBN
                            elif(len(isbn) == 10 and isbn != ISBN_code_digit10):
                                digits10Storage.add(isbn)
                            else:
                                if(isbn != ISBN_code_digit10 and isbn != ISBN_code_digit13):
                                    print "What kind of crap it is? %s" % isbn

            tempRowStorage.append(",".join(str(x) for x in digits13Storage))#writes the 3rd column
            tempRowStorage.append(",".join(str(x) for x in digits10Storage))#...     ...4th...
            outputFileWriter.writerow(tempRowStorage)
        else:
            codes_not_found.append(ISBN_code)

    lineCounter += 1
    print "Appropriate Progress: %s/%s" % (lineCounter, wc) 



inputFile.close()
outputFile.close()

print "%s Job Finished!" %  datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

And the return is

```
2017-06-13 14:10:34 Start Job !
Appropriate Progress: 1/458008
Appropriate Progress: 2/458008
Appropriate Progress: 3/458008
Appropriate Progress: 4/458008
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Downloads/test.py", line 114, in <module>
    html_doc = request.make(query=ISBN_code)#search this ISBN
  File "Downloads/test.py", line 25, in make
    r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=self.headers)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'url' referenced before assignment
```

I do not understand why I have the returned error. There may be some defects in the function *make*, where the code neither goes to if and elif, so url is not assigned? I do not think it is the problem of global or local variable as in this post [UnboundLocalError: local variable 'url_request' referenced before assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798609/unboundlocalerror-local-variable-url-request-referenced-before-assignment) because the code runs until the 4th book it searched(Appropriate Progress: 4/458008). What's also wired is that the output file only records 2 books and their related books when it has searched 4 books.

Comment: Well, think carefully about the logic. `if query`, there's some code to assign the names; and `if resource` there's some code to assign them again. But what if *neither* of those conditions is met?

Answer (score -1):

Your line 25 should say:

```
r = requests.get(self.url, params=params, headers=self.headers)
```

When You try to do this with just 'url', the interpreter will look for the variable 'url' in the current scope (being the make function) where it hasn't been assigned. By using the above code, you tell the interpreter that it should look for the variable'url' inside of the classes own varibles, where you put it in the init function.

Comment: Thank you! But it returns error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'params' referenced before assignment". And if I use params=self.params instead,  it returns "AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'params'".

Comment: This could come from your call just before line 25 where it is possible that you set params to None. This would mean that params is an empty value or in other terms not set. You should either avoid doing this or just check if params is set before using it.

Comment: This is wrong. The previous code is supposed to compute the local variables `url` and `params`, so that this line can use them. The problem is that they **don't always** result in assigning those variables, due to the conditional logic. (Also, the description of how `self` works is... very inaccurate.)